# Displaying byte values in the picturebox control

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, .net-3.5

i am currently working on a project which deals with the reading of satellite images of ".0FM" format and its size is around 8Mb. Now i have been successful in converting the file("*.0FM") content into a byte array. Now the byte array has integer values ranging from 
0 - 255. I have to display this byte array in a picturebox control. Below is the code that i have implemented, (it runs without errors, but nothing is displayed...)
code:

```
Bitmap^ bmp = gcnew Bitmap( 3000 , 3000 );

 long int ct = 0; //...declared as long as there are 80,00,000 elements in buf_int array
 int i,j;

 pictureBox1->Width = 3000;
 pictureBox1->Height = 3000;

for(i=0 ; i<300 ; i++)  
{  
for(j=0 ; j<300 ; j++)  
  {  
   bmp->SetPixel(i,j,Color::FromArgb((int)buf_int[ct] ));  
   pictureBox1->Image = bmp;  
   pictureBox1->Show();
   ct++;
  }

}
```

Plz do help me out on this one, Thanks.....

Comment: buf_int is the byte array having values 0 - 255

Comment: i have purposely set the two "for" loops to loop only 90000 times(i.e 300 x 300), as i wanted to check that does anything display or not..its time consuming to loop for 80,00,000 times...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already answer this.
However, you should rewrite like this:

bmp->SetPixel(Xcount,Ycount,Color::FromArgb((int)buf_int[ct],Color::Black));

The last parameter is the color you want to change over the range of your buffer.